# found unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token only for update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-4-2-1

I have the update method in user managements controller like this

```
def update
  @user.update(user_permitted_params)
  redirect_to admin_user_managements_path
end
```

My strong parameters is set as

```
def user_permitted_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
  :password_confirmation,
  :address, :zip_code,
  :phone_number, :role_id)
end
```

I am getting following issue

> Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, user, commit

Comment: What params do you get from client?

Comment: ok, but why do you care?

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7havX0C2i4Q4FU+bokYKFQrpENi/lrEAawVXo1ubVbxuf5W2bUHXdBoZWZEVnsVb/hC+F6EfKSuPx/Xo9eQG4g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"kurianmathew10@gmail.com", "name"=>"Kurian Mathew", "address"=>"plackattu", "zip_code"=>"", "phone_number"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "role_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"1"}

Comment: Using ActiveAdmin? https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2595

Comment: No i am  not using active domain

Comment: There is no obvious reason for why this is happening based on the code you posted, you may have to post the entire controller. What does params[:user] return?

Comment: jap, the current code looks good. please post the form and the whole controller.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code myself and the only explanation for your error is that you must have called `@user.update(params)` at some point.

Comment: +1 for you! 
This is from 2015, so I am not sure if this will still be accepted these days :/

Comment: I didn't get that golden Unsung Hero badge for no reason :-)