# Rails 5 Independent View Nested Resource - param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested resource called PracticeQuestion, which is a child of PracticeQuiz. I want users to be able to go through one question at a time when they are at a PracticeQuiz. For example: `foo.com/practice_quizzes/1/practice_questions/1..n`

I got the practice quizzes working, but when I try to add a new practice question, I get a rails error that says that the param is missing or empty, but I don't see what i'm doing wrong. Please help

**practice_quiz.rb**

```
class PracticeQuiz < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  validates :user, presence: true
  has_many :practice_questions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**practice_question.rb**

```
class PracticeQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :practice_quiz
end
```

**practice_questions_controller.rb**

```
class PracticeQuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_practice_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @practice_questions = PracticeQuestion.all
  end

  def show
  end

  # GET /practice_questions/new
  def new
    @practice_quiz = PracticeQuiz.friendly.find(params[:practice_quiz_id])
    @practice_question = PracticeQuestion.new
  end

  # GET /practice_questions/1/edit
  def edit
  end


  def create
    @practice_quiz = PracticeQuiz.friendly.find(params[:practice_quiz_id])
    @practice_question = PracticeQuestion.new(practice_question_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @practice_question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @practice_question, notice: 'Practice question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @practice_question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @practice_question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_practice_question
      @practice_question = PracticeQuestion.find(params[:id])
    end

    def practice_question_params
        params.require(:practice_question).permit(:question, :explanation, :flagged)
     end


end
```

**views/practice_questions/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(url: practice_quiz_practice_questions_path, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if practice_question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(practice_question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this practice_question from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% practice_question.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :question %>
    <%= form.text_field :question %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :explanation %>
    <%= form.text_field :explanation %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :practice_quizzes do 
    resources :practice_questions
  end
```

I set the practice_questions controller's new method to find the id of the parent resource, but I get this error. I'm pretty sure I'm following rails naming conventions fine too.

**ActionController::ParameterMissing at /practice_quizzes/23535/practice_questions
param is missing or the value is empty: practice_question**

Update: here's the results from the rails server window

```
Processing by PracticeQuestionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7dpxBB7jjZWzicCYWGA8yeTPSc9UeaqNDOavKQai2vMISryPBiMZ9Zo4LLS3DgZQI8IJc7rLh2TXd9Fj8PAjiA==", "question"=>"235235", "explanation"=>"25235232", "commit"=>"Save ", "practice_quiz_id"=>"23535"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  PracticeQuiz Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "practice_quizzes".* FROM "practice_quizzes" WHERE "practice_quizzes"."slug" = $1 ORDER BY "practice_quizzes"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["slug", "23535"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 102ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: practice_question:
  app/controllers/practice_questions_controller.rb:76:in `practice_question_params'
  app/controllers/practice_questions_controller.rb:30:in `create'
```

Update 2:

**views/practice_questions/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New Practice Question</h1>
<%= render 'form', practice_question: @practice_question %>
```

Comment: Is this the correct path in the form? `practice_quiz_practice_questions_path`

Comment: can you post request params from server log?
are you sure you have `practice_question` as a root parameter name in request?

Comment: And post your new view - are you passing `@practice_question` into the form partial?

Comment: @gwalshington I read a guide that said to use the form_with url setting: ```<%= form_with(url: practice_quiz_practice_questions_path, local: true) do |form| %>``` -- This is what is in the form partial.

Comment: @mazing okay! It's a little unusual, but the error doesn't indicate that is the issue. Just wanted to make sure!  The error is saying that the variable `practice_questions` in the form is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
def practice_question_params
    params.require(:practice_question).permit(:question, :explanation, :flagged)
end
```

you are using rails strong parameters. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30826895/2627121

Basically, `params.require(:practice_question)` means that you must have `practice_question` parameter. 
Here
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"", "question"=>"235235", "explanation"=>"25235232", "commit"=>"Save ", "practice_quiz_id"=>"23535"}`
you have `question` and `explanation` as root parameters, when according to your strong parameters declaration you must have
`"practice_question" => { "question"=>"235235", "explanation"=>"25235232" }`

You should edit form fields to have name as `practice_question[question]`

Comment: Doesn't the error indicate the issue is coming from the PraticeQuiz Load line?  It's followed by `Completed 400 Bad Request in 102ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)`

Comment: the error indicates that `param is missing or the value is empty: practice_question`. Meaning there must be `practice_question` param sent to that action, but there isn't

Comment: Ah, right @gwalshington. That only means that the last executed line of code that wrote something to log(in this case the last SQL request) was loading `PraticeQuiz`. But that doesn't mean the error has occurred right there.